# Why my click button is uploading the count of likes when I reload the page

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

My problem here is that I want to make a like,dislike, hearth and etc buttons, but my problem is that the clicks that I count will upload it to the database but I have to reload it after so it will show up to the client side.

Here is my sample code.

For backend

```
router.route('/update/:id').post((req,res) => {
    
    practice1.findById(req.params.id)
        .then( practice_1 => {

            practice_1.name = req.body.name
            practice_1.number = req.body.number

            practice_1.save()
            .then(() => res.json('Sample Updated!'))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error :' + err))

        })
        .catch()

})

router.route('/update/:id').put((req,res) => {

    practice1.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)
        .then(practice_1 => {
            practice_1.name = req.body.name
            practice_1.number = req.body.number

            practice_1.save()
            .then(() => res.json('Sample Updated!'))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error :' + err))
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error :' + err))

})
```

I did tried to do it in post() and its working though..but It is doing the same thing as the put() where it only updates after I reload the page..
Here is the code for the front end.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Samples = props => (
    <tr>
        <th>{props.sample._id}</th>
        <th>{props.sample.name}</th>
        <th>{props.sample.number}</th>
        <th>
            <button onClick={e => props.addMore(props.sample._id,props.sample)}> Add number </button>
        </th>
    </tr>
)

function ListSample() {
  
    const [samples,setSamples] = useState([])

    // const [sampleadd,setSampleAdd] = useState(0)


    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('http://localhost:1212/practice1')
            .then(data => setSamples(data.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    },[])

    const addMore = (id,samples) => {
        samples.number += 1

        axios.post('http://localhost:1212/practice1/update/'+id,{ name:samples.name , number: samples.number })
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        axios.put('http://localhost:1212/practice1/update/'+id, { name: samples.name, number: samples.number} )
            .then(res => console.log(res.data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

    }

    const sampleDeclarations = () => {
        return samples.map(currentsample => {
            return <Samples 
                key={currentsample._id} 
                sample={currentsample}
                addMore={ e => addMore(e,currentsample)}
            ></Samples>
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Sample List </h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {sampleDeclarations()}
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
    )
}

export default ListSample
```

So basically what I did here in the part of `addMore()` As you see I samples to add the `samples.number += 1` and then give it to put or post..You can just comment out either put or post axios.. I tried it already..but I basically want to automatically upload my count of likes without reloading.

Basically like this in this picture.[image]
Yeah sorry about the namings but just don't mind it.. I just wanna execute it in right method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a state hook, you have to use setSamples. After you do samples.number += 1, try doing

```
setSamples({
...samples,
number = samples.number + 1
});
```

Where ...samples does an object spread getting the rest of the values of the original samples and you are just changing the number parameter. Additionally, maybe change the inside of useState([]) from an empty array to an empty object {} since samples seems to be an object.

Comment: so you mean I will try to setSamples by my id ? right?

Comment: try to see if this helps: [W3 link to useState Hook](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp). But since this is an object, yeah you may have to get the rest of the object so it'd be something like

```
setSamples({
...samples,
number = samples.number + 1
});
```

Comment: Oh my ghad you give me a hint bro... I remember my instagram clone that store a localstorage..Thank you bro. I already solve it thank you brother.

Comment: Your code doesn't work but I already got the hint hahah..

Comment: Awesome that's great to hear! lol what was the proper code you needed?

Comment: there i posted it.